# Center divs to match logo/lead

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my web page I have a centered logo/lead along with two divs below the logo/lead. I wish to make the divs seem centered in accordance to the logo/lead.

I have attempted to center the divs by using Twitter Bootstrap's spans but the divs are still not truly centered.

```
    <div class="row-fluid marketing">
        <div class="span3"></div>
        <div class="span3 text-glow-hover-with-delay">
            <h2><i class="icon-beaker"> </i> Genuinely Tested</h2>
            <p>
                Guru has undergone an enormous amount of testing
                <br />
                via <a href="http://junit.org" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title=""
                data-original-title="Visit their website!">JUnit</a>; the programmer-oriented testing framework.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 text-glow-hover-with-delay">
            <h2><i class="icon-book"> </i> Full Documentation</h2>
            <p>
                We provide full-source/full-documentation for our users.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you need more information you can take a look at the website: http://guru.jire.org

Comment: They actually are centered, look at this screenshot http://d.pr/i/m7b btw I changed the "span4" div to "span3"

Comment: Thanks to you I came up with my own answer.

Comment: Cool, sometimes the background-colors can help when trying to see divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to look at it this way:
[image: example of centering]

The borders on the divs help you see what is happening, the diagonals show you where the true center is.

If you give the divs consistent widths they will look more symmetrical and centered, that may be all you need to get the look you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can make them appear truly centered by changing the *span4* to a *span3* (odd-equality rule) and then setting the divs to align-center. Full source below.

```
    <div class="row-fluid marketing">
        <div class="span3"></div>
        <div class="span3 text-glow-hover-with-delay" align="center">
            <h2><i class="icon-beaker"> </i> Genuinely Tested</h2>
            <p>
                Guru has undergone an enormous amount of testing
                <br />
                via <a href="http://junit.org" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title=""
                data-original-title="Visit their website!">JUnit</a>; the programmer-oriented testing framework.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 text-glow-hover-with-delay" align="center">
            <h2><i class="icon-book"> </i> Full Documentation</h2>
            <p>
                We provide full-source/full-documentation for our users.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```